# Uninstall plugin component with main application

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I have WIX installer for my main application with custom bootstrapper. I have written plugin component (dll) which has separate installer. Plugin dll is deployed thought its own installer at same location as main application deployment. It also marks entry in control panel and in registry.

I want to inform user during uninstall of main application if he wishes to uninstall plugin as well *(if exist)*, if yes- it should uninstall both main and plugin, otherwise only main application.

My question is how do I chain uninstall of Plugin component along with main application?

Comment: Is it at all an option to deliver the plugin along with the main setup? In other words to merge the setups? Or are there compelling reasons why the plugin has to be a separate setup - for example different release schedule, licensing issues, etc...? Using a WiX-bundle you should be able to implement what you are asking for, but merging the plugin setup with the main setup would be my preferred option for reliability reasons.

Comment: yes, Plugin can't go with main setup due to licensing reason. It'll be available to eligible users only. How it can be done using Wix bundle?